# Add calendar control perl win32::GUI application

Tags: perl

I need to add a Calendar control in my desktop application, which developed in Perl Win32::GUI.
Please provide solution to add calendar control using Perl Win32::GUI.

Madhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Win32::GUI::DateTime](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=datetime)
is combo-box with date selection. You can add such widget like this:

```
$MainWin->AddDateTime(
    -name   => "Date",
    -pos    => [10,10],
    -size   => [100, 24],
    -format => 'shortdate'
);
```

Comment: @user696264 - you may consider accepting of the answer, if it works for you. Glad I could help.